# No module named 'pyarrow.lib' found from lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pyarrow

I have installed pyarrow version 0.14.0. I'm creating a package to run that from lambda.
While executing from lambda i'm getting error - No module named 'pyarrow.lib'
I have incorporated pyarrow package to my deployment zip file as well. My python version used is 3.7.

Can someone please help on this issue?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? hitting the same error.

Comment: try with pyarrow==0.13.0

Comment: I tried creating a layer with pyarrow==5.0.0 in AWS Lambda for python 3.8 and I'm running into same issue.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem is that modules like pyarrow port their code from C/ C++. When you check pyarrow codebase, you will find in fact two pyarrow.lib files exist, but they have .pyx and .pxd file extensions. This is not pure Python code and therefore depends on underlying CPU architecture.

Bundling pyarrow with my code in the same zip did not work, irrespective of the .whl file I used. I was able to solve the problem in two ways.

##### 1. Lambda Layer

I had to manually download .whl files for my required version for pyarrow and its dependency numpy. From `http://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/`, click on Download files and search for your matching version. cp39 means cpython 3.9. and x86 represents the CPU architecture. Follow the same steps for Numpy. I ended up downloading these files: `pyarrow-8.0.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl` and `numpy-1.22.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`.

You then have to unzip them and create an archive where both sit together in a folder named `python`. This folder can be used to create a layer in Lambda. Attach this layer to your project and `import pyarrow` should now work.

I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@shimo164/lambda-layer-to-use-numpy-and-pandas-in-aws-lambda-function-8a0e040faa18) for creating a pyarrow layer.

##### 2. Docker container

The other solution is to use custom Docker images. This worked smoothly for me. I believe the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) are exhaustive on that topic. I have written a PoC and all the steps that I followed [here](https://github.com/swakeert/aws_lambda_docker_container).